# Secondary monitor is not correct resolution

Tags: display, multiple-monitors

I have an ASUS K53E laptop running Windows 7 Pro 64-bit with Intel HD 3000 graphics. The resolution of the main monitor on my laptop is 1366x768. I plugged in a secondary monitor at the VGA port and it's not the actual screen resolution (1280x1024). It's only 1024x768. Help me to fix it.

Comment: You might want to include more information in your question.  Things like what Operating System you are running and what you have already tried to resolve the problem would help people solve your problem.

Comment: Are you sure that  it's actual resolution is 1280x1024? I mean how do you know that? From the box or you've checked it on another OS?

Comment: Sorry for missing infomation. I have updated :)